# Newsgroup notification in the indicator applet?

Tags: indicator, thunderbird, notification

Is it possible to get the indicator applet (the mail icon in the top right of the screen) to tell me when someone posts something new in particular newsgroups that I'm subscribed to?

Currently I'm using thunderbird for newsgroups. Running 11.04, 64bit.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [libnotify-mozilla](https://launchpad.net/libnotify-mozilla) application to achieve this, which is made available via a [PPA](https://askubuntu.com/questions/4983/what-are-ppas-and-how-do-i-use-them). Further instructions on installation can be found on [WebUpd8](http://www.webupd8.org/2011/02/thunderbird-indicator-adds-folders.html).